Существует ли отдельное приложение Stack Overflow на русском?
Существует ли приложения для Stack Overflow на русском для ПК(желательно под Linux) и для мобильных устройств(желательно под iOS)?

таких приложений, по крайней мере официальных, нет

что именно ты хотел увидеть в приложении, чего не хватает на сайте, в веб версии?

@Grundy, просто было бы удобнее, если бы ты не каждый раз забивал сайт в Гугле, а заходил в отдельное приложение

Закладки в браузере рулят. Ну или избранное, у кого как называется

@Grundy, уведомления к примеру. То есть не заходить на сайт, а чтоб пуш уведомления приходили, если есть ответ /комментарий итд, а так же к примеру подписаться на к примеру редактирование и если есть задания, чтоб приходили.

Мне кажется, некотрые участники как то используют браузер, или просто он у них открыт весь день, потому как бывает почти сразу отвечают. Может в браузере как то можно пуш настроить. Я не вникала...

Приложений непосредственно для "Stack Overflow на русском" никогда не было. Но были приложения для доступа к различным сайтам сети StackExchange. В какой-то момент было даже выделенное приложение для англоязычного Stack Overflow.
На текущий момент все приложения признаны устаревшими и определённые API отключены. То есть, скорее всего, они даже не позволяют просматривать контент. Я лично раньше пользовался приложениями под iOS и под Android.
На MSE достаточно большое кол-во вопросов по приложениям можно найти по меткам "ios-app" и "android-app".
